# LINQ sorting by number of appearances

Tags: linq, list, sorting, count

I need to sort a list by numer od appearances and show repeating items only once. For example I have a following list : `"a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "d", "c"`. I want it to be sorted like this: `"a","c","b",d"`. How can I achieve this?

That is what I made:

```
var something = from c in db.Letters
             group c by c.letter into p
             orderby p.Count()
             select new
             {
                 p.letter
             };
```

But expression p.letter cannot be used.

Comment: Sounds pretty basic. `GroupBy`, `OrderByDescending` group `Count()`, `Select` group `Key`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can achieve this by writing some code. Please remember that SO is not a free coding service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm trying for 2 hours. All I coded was wrong so I didn't attached it.If you would like to see it wait a minute, please.

Comment: Just use `select p.Key` and you are done :)

Comment: Ah, and `orderby p.Count() descending` - see my first comment.

Comment: @GiladGreen Well, if not counting my first comment 26 mins earlier :) But seriously, I'm with Rene, we should not answer LINQ questions w/o OP showing some effort. As you can see, he's been almost there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var resunt = from c in db.Letters
             group c by c.letter into p
             orderby p.Count() descending
             select p.Key;
```

When you use `GroupBy` you get an `IGroupping` object that contains a property of the `Key` object that you've grouped by and a collection of the values in the group. In your case you want to return the `Key` - the `c.letter`

Comment: I doesn't work. I'm just getting a list sorted alphabetically.

Comment: OK, I added  "orderby p.Count() descending" and it works. Thank you!

Comment: @Artur - it isn't sorted alphabetically but form the one with lowest count to greatest. See edit